# Lambda auto with input function in c++ giving errors

Tags: c++, input, lambda, return, auto

I am trying to make an input function like the one in python `input()` but because of the way functions return variables they must be in the format of the function type `void, int, std::string` so when a user inputs a line it is set to what ever it must return (I.E. `int print()` would mean the return also has to be int so 9 = 57). Here is my current state of code and an example of what I am wanting to happen vs what is happening.

```
//Input
auto input = [](const auto& message = "") {
    std::cout << message;
    const auto& x = std::cin.get();
    return x;
};

const auto& a = input("Input: ");
print(a);
```

With this current code when I type *9* into the console it returns `a` as *57*. I was hoping it would return it as simply *9* but that is obviously not an `int` as I typed it on my keyboard. It also returns the input 'string' as *115*, I have no idea why it does this. Ultimately I would like it to function like pythons `input()` and return it as a string. 9 = 9 and 'string' = 'string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something like python `input()`, I think you should hard code a `std::string` type in this case.

```
auto input = [](const std::string& message = "") {
    std::cout << message;
    std::string x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
};
//print can be auto to be more generic
auto print = [](const auto& message) {std::cout << message << std::endl;};
auto a = input("Input: "); //a is a string 
print(a);
```

If you input a int, and want an int back, you can convert it using stoi

```
auto b = std::stoi(input("Input: ")); //convert string to int, and b is an int
print(b);
```

**UPDATE**
Since python `input` reads the whole line at once, but 
`std::cin >> x;` will only read until the first space,

```
std::getline(std::cin, x);//This will read the whole line including spaces
```

might be a better solution.

Comment: Sweet! Is there a way to allow the `std::cin` to accept no input and close when enter is pressed? At the moment it will continue to ask until a character (*space* not included) is inputed. Note that in python it closes no matter what when enter is pressed

Comment: [`std::cin::operator>>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) will by default only extract the first token from the string, e.g. stop at the first whitespace. That also swallows the newline (that being whitespace) so you can't catch that.

Comment: @Mose I think `std::getline(std::cin, x)` might do the job! I have updated my answer, let me know if it's what you are looking for

Comment: @Mose actually see jmc's answer. it's closer to python input.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin.get();` extracts a character and returns its [ascii value](https://www.asciitable.com/) as an `int`.

When you write `const auto& x = std::cin.get();`, and `'9'` is inserted, the ascii value of `'9'` is returned, which is `57`.

Answer (score 1):

`'9'` != `9`.

In your case (ascii), `'9'` is `54`.
in same way `'s'` (first char of `"string"`) is `115`.

`const auto& x = std::cin.get();` returns an `int`. so your lambda return an int, and so print your character as `int`.

You might use `std::string`:

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
return s;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as a function however I want it to act like pythons version. In this you have to make an input or it will continually ask again when you press enter, (space is also not counted as a character for some reason.). Where in python if you press enter without an input it will continue. Using `.get()` method does this but then only records the first character as @Gill Bates mentioned. Is there a way to achieve this also?

Answer (score 1):

If you want behavior that's closer to the actual Python's `input()` function (actually, `raw_input()` since you can't evaluate Python anyway in this context), you can do like the following:

```
using EOFError = std::exception;

template <typename T = std::string>
std::string raw_input(T prompt = {}) {
  std::cout << prompt;
  std::string line;
  if (!std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    throw EOFError();
  }
  return line;
}
```

This will also detect when you've received EOF (when the stream manipulated by [`getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) is no longer valid -- ideally you should check for the `eofbit` here).